# How do I join the keys of a map in a string?

Tags: groovy

I want to return the keys of a map into a string like this:

```
mymap = [
    aaa: myObj.aaa,
    bbb: myObj.bbb,
    ccc: myObj.ccc
]

def list = [] 
mymap.each{ key, value -> key; list << key}
myStr = list.join('\\\n')
```

I could add them to an array and then join like this but is there a more groovy way to do this? Is there a language construct that can do this in one step?

Comment: How about `mymap.keySet().join('\\\n')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
mymap*.key?.join("\\\n")
```

Comment: Or `mymap.keys()...`

Comment: .keys() doesn't work for me.  What version of groovy is that working in?  .keySet() does work though, as ernest mentioned also.

Comment: You are correct!  Mixed up my programming languages.. ;)

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who does that!  :-)